# How to correctly alias a table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to do a join between 2 tables from my db.

this is my code:

```
public function getEpisodes($limit = 12, $order = 'id_e', $das = 'desc')
        {
            $this->db->select('e.id_e, e.id_s, e.num_e, s.id_s, s.nom_s, s.thumb_s')
                     ->from('s_episodes as e, s_series as s')
                     ->join('s', 'e.id_s = s.id_s', 'left')
                     ->order_by('e.'.$order, $das)
                     ->limit($limit);
            $query = $this->db->get();

            return $query->result_array();
        }
```

This is the error code I get, when running my code:

[image]

What is wrong with my table alias?

Comment: Please post your error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try moving the `s_series as s`...

```
public function getEpisodes($limit = 12, $order = 'id_e', $das = 'desc')
    {
        $this->db->select('e.id_e, e.id_s, e.num_e, s.id_s, s.nom_s, s.thumb_s')

               // Move s_series as s
                 ->from('s_episodes as e')
                 ->join('s_series as s', 'e.id_s = s.id_s', 'left')


                 ->order_by('e.'.$order, $das)
                 ->limit($limit);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
    }
```